# Does Intel HD Family fit min graphics requirement for BB 10 Alpha Simulator

Tags: graphics, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I am trying to run BB10 Simulator to port my web app.  The simulator runs okay until the point where I launch any apps on the simulator, then the app crashes and never loads.  The fact that the simulator runs makes me think I fit the minumum requirement.

But after looking at my graphics card, I am not sure I do.  Hence, the app crashes on the sim.  Does Intel HD Family graphics cards fit the min graphics requirment of `NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT or higher or an ATI Radeon HD 2600 or higher`?

Answer (score 0):

The BB10 simulator doesn't really use GPU acceleration and I've successfully used it on a MacMini (i5 HD3000) and a Lenovo Laptop (i3 HD3000).

The simulator run the real OS, so unlike Ripple, if you do something forbidden (writing somewhere you’re not supposed to, accessing a resource you didn’t request – PIM, BBM ID, Internet) then the QNX kernel kills you. (Double-check the bar-descriptor.xml)

I’ve never used webworks, but it may be a good idea to install the Native SDK: Momentics (The C++/Cascades IDE) can be frightening, but there is a “QNX Device” perspective that can open a browser to the {simulator|real phone} file system and access to logs. You will have more detail explaining why your application was killed.